# Prove that $A_2^n$ can be partitioned into faces of dimensions $k_1, k_2, ...., k_r$.

Tags: coding-theory, combinatorial-designs

This is part of course on Orthogonal Array.

Suppose that you have given the following equation:
$$\sum_{j=1}^{r}2^{k_j} = 2^n$$ Then, Proof that there is a partitions of $A_2^n$ into faces of dimensions $k_1, k_2, ..., k_r$.

For example: $A^3_2$ can be partitioned into 5 faces of dimensions 1,1,1,0,0. by the summation you see that this is true. The question is to prove that we can partitioned the set into r sets. Now, how to prove that? Do I need to show that the equation in the equality is hold for $0 \leq k_j \leq n$ or that is not enough

We can define the faces of dimension as following:

> $A_q^n = |^{a_1,a_2, ...,a_n}_{l_1, l_2, ..., l_n}$ where $0 \leq a_i \leq q-1$. So, any codeword is membership of this set. let's see the example.

For example: for $A_2^3$ the faces of dimension:$|^{1,0}_{1,2}$ which is the codeword of first position = 1 and second position = 0. So we have $|^{1,0}_{1,2}=\{(101),(100)\}$

In this question, I'm looking to find intuitive idea of the proof rather than the proof.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, here's a sketch for a proof, using infinite descent (or "inverse induction"): Let $(k_1,\ldots,k_r)$ be a counterexample which is minimal with respect to $r$. Under that condition, show that all $k_i$ must be distinct. From this you derive that $r=1$ and $k_1=n$ which contradicts the assumption. Done.

Comment: let me clear something. You want to prove by inverse induction; because it holds the property of infinite set whereas induction proof has the property where you have finite set. Thus, we cannot use induction proof in this way. Because I'm asking myself why not use forward induction proof instead, I just don't understand why in particular we use inverse induction in this case

Comment: Oh, of course you can use forward induction instead of inverse induction; they are completely equivalent. The only reason why sometimes one is preferred over the other is that in some cases it seems somewhat less artificial.